# Is there built in method for sync rezise animation in jquery?

Tags: jquery, animation, synchronization

I make simple accordeon (like this)
|opened||
with jquery and i need expand clicked slide and collapse other.
Width of all slides  is equal.

It's good to make this with something like..

```
$(this)
.next().animate({width: 160}, 500, "easeOutQuad")
.siblings("dd").animate({width: 0}, 500, "easeOutQuad");
```

but i have shaking pixel in last slide button during animation, becouse resize isn't sync.
**UPD**
(actually on every frame function counts current width with float numbers and round it to
integer
when we start two animation on some frames we have two numbers, which rounded floor
and it leads to lose one pixel)
I can use "step" function to set width = (width-this.width) to collapsing slide on each
 frame, but i know that there is simpliest solution.
Thanks.

Slowmotion Example
http://jsfiddle.net/7tSMh/2/
click on green rect and look carefully at last, blue rect. do it n times if didn't see problem.

**UPD**
There is no problem in Firefox
Chrome only

Comment: I will put this as comment instead of answer because it wont be a valid answer.
If you consider this as answer let me know and ill post it.
But check this link http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#default

You can view the source code etc so its basicly copy paste

Comment: Teun Pronk, just make some click on this accordeon and look to last item. Do you see what i mean?

Comment: More or less. do you have a demo?
Is it online or just local? if local could you try to put it on jsfiddle please, so its more clear to me what your problem is. maybe its just me but I cant really visualize the problem.

Comment: ok, here http://jsfiddle.net/7tSMh/1/

Comment: I dont see any problems :/ okay so there is a bit of lag perhaps, but thats just sometimes. not sure if that can be helped. I also see that in the second animation so. sorry :/

Comment: click on green rect and look carefully at last, blue rect. You can set animation speed to 3000ms if very fast

Comment: Sorry cant find anything that will solve this problem. I hope someone else will be able to find it out.

Answer (score 0):

Consider implementing a custom animation.
Have a look at the section titled "Step Function" within the [jQuery .animate() docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). You could write your selector to include all of the elements at once, and use a custom function that detects which element it is currently being called on.

This should at least mostly fix your issue of the interleaved animations that you are seeing by calling `.animate()` on two different sets of elements at the same time.